# Dictionary too big, keys are tuples... options?

Tags: python-2.7

program takes a list of words (70) and makes a dict.The keys are sequences of words in a tuple, where the last letter is the first letter of the next one; the value is a list of the remaining words that start with the last letter of the key.

example:

```
words= ['boy', 'young', 'star', 'grate']

d1={('boy'):['young'], ('young'):['grate'], ('star'):[], ('grate'):[]}

d2={('boy', 'young'):['grate']}

d3={('boy', 'young', 'grate'):[]}
```

I make longer and longer chains of these words recursively

```
d3=makedic(d2,d1)
d4=makedic(d3,d1)
d5=makedic(d4,d1)
```

etc....

since each word can only be used once,. it will taper off eventually however when I reach d15

```
len(d15)
741793
d16=makedic(d15,d)
Killed
```

I assume i'm running out of memory, I cant use db because the keys are tuples, Any ideas on how I can keep going?

Comment: Do you need to keep the earlier dicts around after making the next?  If not, just `del` them, or, even better, just use one variable and keep assigning the result of `makedic` to it.

Comment: Yup, I did. It originally stopped at 13.

Comment: You may simply have too many possibilities to manage: for a group of only 30 words I had 1856284 chains in one case (admittedly that was an unusually large number).  In one 34 word case I had 2978802 sequences simply beginning with "succeeds".

Comment: I guess the word choice matters, The words I was using were pokemon #45 on http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/python_exercises.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to save some memory might be to store indexes to the words instead of the words themselves. For example, in the sentence "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog," you could represent ("jumped", "dog") as (5, 9), since they are the 5th and 9th words in the string.

More generally, I wonder if you actually need to go beyond the two-word case, since every three-word combination must exist as two two-word combinations, right? You might not need to store those larger combinations, and just generate them as you need them.

Comment: That's Genius Thanks, After you mentioned it, I could have instead of integers just cut every word to just the first and last letter; after solving it, it tapered right after 16 so I just needed a little bit more space..  I actually took the easy road and rented out an X-large instance on amazon aws for 10 minutes.The longest chain was 23 words (there were a bit less then 2000 different chains) the problem I was solving is #45 on http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/python_exercises.html